when i run npm start on jhipster project i had blank page on the browser
enter image description here
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
at __webpack_require
I try npm start on jhipster projetc(spring boot / angular) ?
I got blank page on the browser and  this problem on the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
at __webpack_require

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
